# C# TreeView Programmatically Adding Child Nodes With GrandChildren And So On

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm currently working on a WinForm which is containing a TreeView.
Somehow I can not manage to fill the TreeView properly.

**For more visibility:**

```
Parent Device -
              |-ChildDevice1-
              |             |-GrandChild1 (not connected with ChildDevice2)
              |-ChildDevice2

AnotherParentDevice...

and so on...
(this is how it should look like)
```

I tried to give the devices an index-number to identify the parent and the child.

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Parent"));
treeView1.Nodes[parentid].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Child"));
treeView1.Nodes[parentid].Nodes[childid].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("GrandChild"));
```

I could go with the solution above, but the devices can have infinite children and I can't go like:

```
treeView1.Nodes[parentid].Nodes[childid].Nodes[GrandChild1].Nodes[GrandChild2].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("GrandChild2"));
```

I guess you guys understand.

EDIT:
The Method I'm using is going through the registry, and gives back the USB Device Description, if the Device has any child, the method is going in again and gives back the child (and so on). That's why I need a tree

PS.: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Use collection of collection of collection ... etc and **recursion** to fill such tree. Collection can be anything (`IList`, `IEnumerable`, ...).

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: Sinatr, thanks for you answer i will try it.
@Servy, the input is always a string. The Method I'm using is going through the registry, and gives back the USB Devices Description, if the Device has any child, the method is going in again and gives back the child. That's why I need a tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution myself.

Since I'm using a recursive method it is not neccessary to give the parents an id. Because they already have one.

My code looks like this:

```
    //Generate variables for the recursive Method
    TreeView tree = treeView1;
    TreeNode treeNode;

    //You set the current Node to be the Parent
    treeNode = tree.Nodes.Add("rootDevice");

    //Now if the root device has a child
    treeNode = tree.Nodes.Add("childDevice");

    // If the child has a child
    treeNode = tree.Nodes.Add("grandChildDevice");
```

And so on. 
The Method will jump back and use the next root Device as Parent. It was simple as that.